# Function or return with error in join - Linq

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, join

There is somenthing wrong in my function or in return when I trying to show ALL data from a join in my Web Service:

This is the code:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<string> tballtrafo2()
    {
        var alltrafo = from e in objapi.TBEquipamento
                       join u in objapi.TBUnidade on e.idEquipamento equals u.idUnidade
                       select new { e.idEquipamento, u.idUnidade, e.TipoEquipamento,e.Local,
                       e.NumSerie, e.TAG, e.Potencia_KVA, e.TensaoPrimaria_V, e.TensaoSecundaria_V,
                       e.Fabricante, e.AnoFabricacao, e.Volume_L, e.Operacao, e.DataReforma };

        return alltrafo.AsQueryable();
    }
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: And how does it manifest? Errors? Wrong results? What should be the result? Please explain.

Comment: Easy: allTrafo is of type IQueryable<some temp class>. This is not an IQueryable<String>

Comment: Manifest with erros. I would like to make a join with two tables ( TBEquipamento and TBUnidade). but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning anonymous `IQueryable<object>` not `IQueryable<string>` so either return a specific type or correct the return type as `IQueryable<object>`

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<object> tballtrafo2()
{
    var alltrafo = from e in objapi.TBEquipamento
                   join u in objapi.TBUnidade on e.idEquipamento equals u.idUnidade
                   select new { e.idEquipamento, u.idUnidade, e.TipoEquipamento,e.Local,
                   e.NumSerie, e.TAG, e.Potencia_KVA, e.TensaoPrimaria_V, e.TensaoSecundaria_V,
                   e.Fabricante, e.AnoFabricacao, e.Volume_L, e.Operacao, e.DataReforma };

    return alltrafo.AsQueryable();
}
```